# D3 oncontext menu , change node color selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have nodes (that are rectangles) with a right click menu, I am trying to change the color on the node depending on the outcome of the onclick menu but the nodes don't change colors. I have different ways/attempts in the code to see what I may be doing wrong. There are alot of forums with onclick doubleclick, but not with oncontextmenu. Any help would be great and thanks

```
var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
.data(json.nodes)
.enter().append("g")
.attr("r", 12)
.attr("class", "node")
.attr("class", "gLink")
.call(node_drag)
.on('contextmenu', function(d,i) {
       d3.selectAll('.context-menu').data([1])
        .enter()
        .append('div')
        .attr('class', 'context-menu');
      // close menu
      d3.select('body').on('click.context-menu', function() {
        d3.select('.context-menu').style('display', 'none');
      });
      // this gets executed when a contextmenu event occurs
      d3.selectAll('.context-menu')
        .html('')
        .append('ul')
        .selectAll('li')
          .data(actions).enter()
          .append('li')

      .on('click' , function(d) { 

            if (d=="Force Succeed"){ 
                 alert(d);
                 d3.select(".node").style("fill", "#000");
             }
           else  if (d=="Start Node"){ 
         alert(d);
                 d3.select(this).style("fill", "#000000");
             }
    else  if (d=="Start Tree"){ 
                 alert(d);
                 d3.select(this).style("fill", "#000");
             }
    else   { 
                 alert(d);
                 d3.select(this).style("fill", "#000");
             }
           })
          .text(function(d) { return d; });
      d3.select('.context-menu').style('display', 'none');
      // show the context menu
      d3.select('.context-menu')
        .style('left', (d3.event.pageX - 2) + 'px')
        .style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 2) + 'px')
        .style('display', 'block');
      d3.event.preventDefault();
  });



node.append("svg:rect")
   .attr("x", function(d) { return -1 * (d.name.length * 10) / 2 })
   .attr("y", -15)
   .attr("rx", 5)
   .attr("ry", 5)
   .attr("width", function(d) { return d.name.length * 10; })
   .attr("height", 20)
   .style("fill", "#FFF")
   .style("stroke", "#6666FF");
```

Comment: please jsfiddle link

Comment: From your code my guess is that the `d3.select(this).style(...)` statements probably aren't working because the context of `this` has changed. Since the click event is bound to your `li` elements, `this` will refer to some `li` element, whereas you most likely want to be setting the fill of a `rect`.

Comment: I figured as much :-/ How would I get the node then? I am trying to put it up on jsfiddle but unfortunately it is not cooperating with me. I'll keep trying to put it up. To step back and get the node how what syntax is there?

Comment: The easier option would be to simply have a global variable which you set with `this` in the `oncontextmenu` function. The other option would be to 'pass through' the bound data using `.datum` on the `li`, and then in the `click` function you could grab the original item using the data.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep a reference to the object that was right-clicked for the context menu:

```
.on('contextmenu', function(d, i) {

  var self = d3.select(this); //<-- keep this reference

  d3.selectAll('.context-menu').data([1])
   .enter()

  ...

    .on('click', function(d) {
      if (d == "Force Succeed") {
        self.style("fill", "green"); //<-- use it later

  ...
```

---

Here's a functional example, extrapolated from your code snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', 500)
      .attr('height', 500);

    var json = {};
    json.nodes = [
      0, 1, 2, 3
    ];
    
    var actions = ["Force Succeed", "Start Node", "Start Tree"];

    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(json.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 12)
      .attr("cx", function(d){
        return d * 30 + 15;
      })
      .attr("cy", 15)
      .on('contextmenu', function(d, i) {
        
        var self = d3.select(this);
        
        d3.selectAll('.context-menu').data([1])
          .enter()
          .append('div')
          .attr('class', 'context-menu');
        // close menu
        d3.select('body').on('click.context-menu', function() {
          d3.select('.context-menu').style('display', 'none');
        });
        // this gets executed when a contextmenu event occurs
        d3.selectAll('.context-menu')
          .html('')
          .append('ul')
          .selectAll('li')
          .data(actions).enter()
          .append('li')

        .on('click', function(d) {
            if (d == "Force Succeed") {
              self.style("fill", "green");
            } else if (d == "Start Node") {
              self.style("fill", "red");
            } else if (d == "Start Tree") {
              self.style("fill", "blue");
            } else {
              self.style("fill", "#000");
            }
          })
          .text(function(d) {
            return d;
          });
        d3.select('.context-menu').style('display', 'none');
        // show the context menu
        d3.select('.context-menu')
          .style('left', (d3.event.pageX - 2) + 'px')
          .style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 2) + 'px')
          .style('display', 'block')
          .style('position', 'absolute');
        d3.event.preventDefault();
      });

    node.append("svg:rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return -1 * (3 * 10) / 2
      })
      .attr("y", -15)
      .attr("rx", 5)
      .attr("ry", 5)
      .attr("width", function(d) {
        return 3 * 10;
      })
      .attr("height", 20)
      .style("fill", "#FFF")
      .style("stroke", "#6666FF");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```